# How can I list all layouts and corresponding variants that don't use 3rd level symbols?

Tags: grep, keyboard-layout, xkb

I need to list all possible `xkb` layouts and their respective variants that do not use 3rd-level symbols. Manually review of all files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` directory is crazy, there maybe an easier way?

Comment: @don_crissti so, it works, but it doesn't completely solve problem. US layout for example missing in the list, but some variants ("basic" or "dvorak" e.g.) nevertheless don't use 3rd level symbols. I.e. I need parsing of all possible layouts and variants.

Comment: My idea after your comment - if `xkb_symbols "*" {` equally `include "level3(ralt_switch)"`, then all variants of this layout include 3rd level symbols. Maybe after that it will be possible to continue parsing manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could process the list of all layouts and for each item in the list check every corresponding variant for *level3* symbols:

```
list=($(sed '/! layout/,/^$/!d;//d
s/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]].*/\1/' \
< /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst))

layouts=("${list[@]##*/}")

for i in "${layouts[@]}"; do
sed -n '\|//.*level3|d;H;/xkb_symbols/{s/.*"\(.*\)".*/'"${i}:"'\1/;h}
/^};/{x;/level3/d;s/\n.*//p}' < /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/${i}
done
```

The first `sed` lists all layouts in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst` and saves the result in the array `list`. The elements of this array are then further processed via param expansion to get only the layout name (e.g. extract `jp` from `nec_vndr/jp`) and saved into the array `layouts`.
Then, for each `item` in `layouts` the corresponding `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/${item}` file is processed to extract the variants that have no *level3* symbols: `sed` first `d`eletes all commented lines that contain `level3`, then unconditionally appends each line to `H`old buffer. It edits the line containing the variant name prepending the layout name and overwriting the `h`old buffer, then, at the end of each variant section (`/^};/`) it e`x`changes buffers, deleting the pattern space if it contains `level3` else printing only the first line (i.e. *layout:variant*). So the result is something like this:

```
us:basic
us:ibm238l
us:dvorak
us:dvorak-l
us:dvorak-r
us:dvorak-classic
us:dvp
us:olpc2
us:chr
us:carpalx
us:carpalx-full
us:alt-intl-unicode
us:sun_type6
............
dk:nodeadkeys
dk:winkeys
dk:mac
dk:mac_nodeadkeys
dk:dvorak
dk:sun_type6
............
```